# Where else can you specify memory limits in PHP?

Tags: php, memory

I'm getting a common error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1369 bytes)
```

However I've set my memory limit to 512MB in my php.ini, my .htacess and at the beginning of my file with ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');

Shouldn't the allowed memory size in the error message be much higher than 0.25MB? Is there some place else that might be overriding this setting?

Comment: Which OS do you use? Maybe you changed the wrong php.ini. Did you restart your Apache?

Comment: Also note that if there is a flaw in your script, it doesnt matter how much memory you allocate it will never be enough

Comment: Did you open the php.ini file and updated the conf there or just used php_ini?

Comment: don't forget httpd.conf, though any values there should be overridden by the .htaccess and ini_set() stuff.

Comment: I'm running XAMPP on windows 7 and edited the php.ini within that directory. Shouldn't the ini_set override whatever is in there anyway? The code is creating a large array with over 800 entries which is what is breaking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, having different values for the memory limit between my php.ini and my .htaccess was causing the problem...

Answer (score 0):

PHP's memory limit is overruled by the limit of the server (Apache?) if it is lower, so it could be in your web server configuration.

Also note that, especially in Windows, there can be multiple PHP.ini files (one in the Windows folder). Make sure you edit the right one.

Answer (score 0):

If you set it in php.ini you can always put `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in a file and make sure memory_limit is what you expect. If not, you may be updated the wrong php.ini or if you on a shared host they may not allow you to update via php.ini. You can also update using .htaccess by adding `php_flag memory_limit 512M`

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think to check phpinfo(); It is definitely picking up the correct memory limit of 512M, so now I'm really confused as to why it's only making 0.25M available.

Comment: Are you using a CMS or framework that may be overwriting it within a config file?

Comment: This code is interfacing with magento, so yea that might be something, I'll investigate.

Comment: I believe magento may have a .htaccess file which overwrites it. Look through .htaccess files for the memory_limit